# How to change RepositoryItem as label

Tags: devexpress

I have a column where it needs to change to hyperlink to label(Non clickable) based on results set.I am unable to achieve it by `DevExpress.XtraEditors.Repository.RepositoryItemHyperLinkEdit`.Please suggest me what i need to do to achiev this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [GridView.CustomRowCellEdit](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsGridGridView_CustomRowCellEdittopic) event to provide a cell with different repository items based on your condition. When you need to display a hyper link, use RepositoryItemHyperLinkEdit. Otherwise, RepositoryItemTextEdit:

```
private void gridView1_CustomRowCellEdit(object sender, CustomRowCellEditEventArgs e) {
   if (your condition)
      e.RepositoryItem = repositoryItemHyperLinkEdit1;
   else
       e.RepositoryItem = repositoryItemTextEdit1;        
}
```

Comment: I need a blank column with arrow cursor.I am unable to make the RepositoryItemTextEdit1 value as empty.